# get sqlalchemy to pull entire column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In regular sql I can pull an entire column via "select * from table", I can not find an equivalent in sqlalchemy.

I am trying to pull all the usernames from my table User. All I have found so far is models.User.query.all() and then performing a for loop to pull the columns I want, but I am lead to believe this is terrible practice as it pulls the entire table when I only want 1 column.

models.py

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    #mobilitys = db.relationship('Mobility', backref='username', lazy='dynamic')
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __repr__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return '<user> %r' % (self.username)
```

Terminal trying to do with_entities

```
>>> from app import db, models
>>> models.User.query.with_entities(User.username)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'User' is not defined
>>> models.User.username
<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7fccb4f682f0>
```

terminal view for follow up questions:

```
jsnyder10@jsnyder10-VirtualBox:~$ cd Documents/45
jsnyder10@jsnyder10-VirtualBox:~/Documents/45$ source env/bin/activate
(env) jsnyder10@jsnyder10-VirtualBox:~/Documents/45$ flask/bin/python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from models import User
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named models
>>> from .models import User
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

2nd terminal view:

```
(env) jsnyder10@jsnyder10-VirtualBox:~/Documents/45$ flask/bin/python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from app import db, models
>>> from models import User
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named models
>>> from .models import User
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [with_entities()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities) method to restrict which columns you'd like to return in the result. eg:

```
result = User.query.with_entities(User.username)
```

or with sqlalchmey session:

```
result = session.query(User.username)
```

Comment: So I tried that in my terminal and it claimed User was undefined. To demonstrate it is defined I ran User.username afterward. I posted the results at the bottom of the original question.

Comment: you didn't import `User` , that's why your second `User` is not defined, you can also add the `models` like this `models.User.query.with_entities(models.User.username)` , or `from models import User` so that u can use `User` directly.

Comment: When I try from models import User it gives me ImportError: No module named models. When I try from .models import User it gives me ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package. Is there a way around this so I can play with the code form the terminal?

Comment: have you `from app import db, models` before  `from models import User`?

Comment: I have tried that, it give me this error ImportError: No module named models. In my code when I import it I use from .models import User. The terminal however does not allow me to do this.

Comment: can u share all code what you input in the terminal?

Comment: Just added it to the bottom of the question, I don't know how to put code in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144887/discussion-between-tiny-d-and-new-to-python).

Comment: you have to import the `models` first, then you can use `models`, in the terminal, first run `from app import db, models`, then `from models import User`